# Electron default entire proxy

Tags: performance, proxy, electron

I find my question is like this https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/5449

There are a lot of request in My application, e.g, oauth request, loading online image.

I wonder how to set 'default' proxy to my entire electron application.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I found how to do that

```
mainWindow.webContents.session.setProxy({ proxyRules: 'direct://' }, () => {})
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SLZ4.png)